# transition.to( ) doesn't work within a function and with a Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", method) listener in Corona / Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So here's my problem. I am working on some Lua code using Corona SDK, for an iPhone app. I have narrowed the problem down to a few lines of code, that, if made to work, can point me in the right direction for the actual code. ( Plus, posting the original code will only make this post longer :P). So here goes:

```
local square = display.newRect( 0, 0, 100, 100 )
square:setFillColor( 255,255,255 )

local function move(event)
    transition.to( self, { time=1500, alpha=0, x=100, y=100 } )
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", move)
```

Basically, the problem is that the transition.to( ) method does not work in a function that has an "enterFrame" listener. If I change the listener on the last line to

```
timer.performWithDelay( )
```

or even

```
Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", method)
```

it suddenly works.

I have no idea what I am missing. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `enterFrame` listener is called by the Corona runtime every time the screen is refreshed--probably 30 frames per second.  So every 33 ms, you start an animation on the square, which takes 1500 ms to complete.  Just as it gets started, you add yet another animation. And so on.  You should use this event to handle animations that you have to manage directly because the movement or changes are beyond the capabilities of the transition functions.  The whole point of using the transition functions is to avoid the need for this kind of direct control for most animations.

The `touch` listener is called only when the user touches the screen,  so you don't get repeated invocations of the `move` event.  The `performWithDelay` method also calls the `move` event just once.  You probably want to use one of these approaches.

Comment: Basically, I need an image to move in a looping path (let's say 0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0) until I tap it, in which case another funciton is called. Would you say I can do that with the onComplete parameter, and different functions for each of the four points in the path?

Comment: Yes, that is how I would approach it.  Track the current transition in a local variable so that you can terminate it in the touch event handler.  (`transition.to()` returns a handle, which you use later in `transaction.cancel()`.)