# Transition.to not moving object properly - Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a table full of enemies and simple want them to move across the screen via gameLoop, however for some reason nothing seems to work. Its probably an easy fix but I have tried to fix it but am getting nowhere. Anyone know whats up?

**gameLoop Function**

```
local i 
 for i = 1, #enemies do--.numChildren,1, -1 do 
    local blocks = enemies[i]
    if blocks ~= nil and blocks.x ~= nil then 
        enemyRate = 2.0 + (0.1 * wave)
        transition.to( blocks, { time=1500, x=300} )
    end
 end
```

**The Spawn Function**

```
function spawnEnemy()

local spawnData = { -- Easily store spawns in a table to make it easier to add new enemies later

{name = "Blue", seq = "blueRect", frame = 3, imgSheet = imageSheetRectangle, seqData = sequenceDataRectangle},
{name = "Red", seq = "blueCross", frame = 1, imgSheet = imageSheetCross, seqData = sequenceDataCross},
{name = "Green", seq = "blueCirc", frame = 2, imgSheet = imageSheetCircle, seqData = sequenceDataCircle}
}

local xPos = display.contentWidth - 150
local r = math.random(1, #spawnData)

local sd = spawnData[r] -- get the spawn data for this enemy 

local s = display.newSprite(sd.imgSheet, sd.seqData)
s.name = sd.name
physics.addBody(s, { isSensor = true })
s:setSequence(sd.seq)
s:setFrame(sd.frame)
s.y = display.contentHeight - 400
s.x = xPos
enemies[#enemies+1] = s
enemyGroup:insert(s)
```

Comment: This looks like it will move them to a static `x` position of `300`. Is that what you wanted? Is *anything* happening when this runs?

Comment: I don't see an issue with any of the code here. Can you link a bit more of your code?

Comment: Hey guys, its very weird that nothing happens. @EtanReisner: yes its ok for them to be static values as they get destroyed when they move off screen.

Comment: @BrettComardelle: Thats the main part of the code for moving the objects. I could show you how I am spawning them if that helps. I will update the post

Comment: What is `enemyRate` supposed to do? And is your screen smaller than `300` units in the `x` direction? Because, unless I misunderstood the `transition.to` function, this isn't going to *move* them `300` units every time it is going to send to exactly `x` unit location `300` every time (which means they won't appear to move at all).

Comment: EnemyRate was just a value to move the enemy by. I was trying to hardcode it and increase the speed during gameplay. The simulator device is set to iPhone 5, it basically spawns at Xpos (updated code above) and just stays there

Comment: Did you ensure that your enemies table is in the scope of use for your gameloop because maybe your blocks = nil and is not executing the transition? @EtanReisner it moves them to 300 over the span of 1.5 seconds.

Comment: @BrettComardelle The first time, yes. Then they will just sit still (I would assume). I assumed this was supposed to be progressing them across the screen in `300` unit increments each loop or something like that. But maybe with the initial position at `contentWidth - 150` that's not true and the static transition is fine.

Comment: I'm not certain, but it is likely that your transition is executing, but because it is in the gameloop, it is executing every frame. This MAY be setting them back to the original position and is making them appear as they are not moving. Why not begin their transition right when they are spawned in the spawn function?

Comment: I definitely don't see any animation. the x position -150 contentW was so that I could actually see the object spawn in view and then see if it does move across, instead all that happens is they stay unmoved and the spawns just sit on top of each other. They definitely aren't moving

Comment: @BrettComardelle: Regarding the transition being inside gameloop, and running every frame: object:translate seems to work fine, shouldn't that have a problem as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this related answer: [transition.to( ) doesn't work within a function and with a Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", method) listener in Corona / Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268710/transition-to-doesnt-work-within-a-function-and-with-a-runtimeaddeventliste) you can see a similar issue as I stated above. You are creating an animation right as one is starting - making it seem as though it is not moving. As I suggested above, if it suits your game, begin the transition when you spawn the object; not every gameloop.

Comment: I was just about to comment here that after taking it out from gameLoop, it looks to be working fine from within the spawn function. Thanks for the help guys